# Getting unique values of pairs in an RDD when the order within the pair is irrelevant

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a rdd with the values of

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
b,a
c,d
d,c
d,e
```

what I need is an rdd that contains the reciprocal pairs, but just one set. It would have to be:

```
a,b  or b,a
c,d  or d,c
```

I was thinking they could be added to a list and looped thru to find the the opposite pair, if one exists filter the first value out, and delete the reciprocal pair.  I am thinking there must be a way of using scala functions like join or case, but I am having difficulty understanding them

Comment: are the elements, say, 'a' and 'b' comparable (ca be sorted in some way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the order of each pair to change(e.g., (a,b) to become (b,a)), you can give a simple and easy to parallelize solution. The examples below use numbers but the pairs can be anything; as long as the values are comparable.

In vanilla Scala:

```
List(
 (2, 1), 
 (3, 2), 
 (1, 2), 
 (2, 4), 
 (4, 2)).map{ case(a,b) => if (a>b) (a,b) else (b,a) }.toSet
```

This will result in:

```
res1: Set[(Int, Int)] = Set((2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 2))
```

In Spark RDD the above can be expressed as:

```
sc.parallelize((2, 1)::(3, 2)::(2, 1)::(4, 2)::(4, 2)::Nil).map{ case(a,b) => 
   if (a>b) (a,b) else (b,a) }.distinct()
```

Comment: So (3,2) should be in the output despite its reciprocal pair not being present? That surprises me, but it certainly makes the problem easier.